# Awaiting a method that makes an axios call to an API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I wish to make an API call before executing any additional code. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as the code executes synchronously before the *.then* method is executed within the axios get call:

```
checkData() {
   return this.$axios.get(url)
      .then(result => { //
      })
      .catch(() => { //
      })
}
```

since *checkData* returns a promise from *axios.get* I would assume it can be awaited in an async method and the code executes only *after* *checkData()* has been executed completely.
Unfortunately this is not the case:

```
async myMethod() {
    await checkData()
    // do some stuff
}
```

and some stuff continues executing synchronously even before the *then* or *catch* inside *checkData()* have been executed (as I assume this resolves the promise).

Comment: there are multiple solutions based on your question, but first you need to fully describe your situation, like where do you want to use your function? what do you want to do after it's called? and what is the stuff that are working incorrectly

Comment: If you need help, consider presenting a *runnable* [mcve] featuring the described bug. What you've shown so far is not enough to repro.